# How to remove (and put to new df) all the records that have the same value in two first columns but different in third one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a df:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
x     y    [z]    [w]
x     y    [s]    [w]
c     d    [a]    [b]
c     d    [f]    [g]
t     p    [q]    [l]
t     p    [q]    [w]
```

Now, I want to remove all the records that have the same values in col1 and col2 but different in col 3 and put them in a new df. So after this processing I would get two df's. The old one:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
t     p    [q]    [l]
t     p    [q]    [w]
```

And the new one, with extracted records:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
x     y    [z]    [w]
x     y    [s]    [w]
c     d    [a]    [b]
c     d    [f]    [g]
```

How can I achieve such a thing?

@Edit:
values in col3 and col4 are actually lists. I edited the example to match this criteria

Comment: The text you wrote does not correspond with the example output

Comment: can you edit your question, your example doesn't make sense :)

But i guess you should create 3 dataframes

Comment: @guiguilecodeur Yes, my bad. Sorry for the inconvenience. Now this should be good.

Comment: @gtomer I edited the example. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: convert your `list` to `frozenset` to be hashable. You also may want to use `tuple`, it depends on if the order of values does matter.

You can use `groupby_nunique` with `transform` to broadcast the result over rows. Now you have a boolean mask to separate dataframes:

```
m = (df.assign(col3=df['col3'].apply(frozenset))
       .groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3']
       .transform('nunique').eq(1))
df_old = df[m]
df_new = df[~m]
```

Output:

```
>>> df_old
  col1 col2 col3 col4
4    t    p  [q]  [l]
5    t    p  [q]  [w]

>>> df_new
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    x    y  [z]  [w]
1    x    y  [s]  [w]
2    c    d  [a]  [b]
3    c    d  [f]  [g]
```

Comment: Hey, this seems to be perfect - there happened to be another thing - values in col3 and col4 are arrays and your method seems to throw out the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Do you have any idea on dealing with that? Sorry for the misinformation

Comment: It should not be a big deal. Convert your lists as frozenset before. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Does it solve your problem?